# Running a child activity a second time

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I am trying to write a custom CompositeActivity using WF3.5. Something like a WhileActivity.

The problem is when I want to execute the child activity again (it previously succeeded with a final call to ActivityExecutionContext.CloseActivity()) I get an InvalidOperationException, with this message: "Activity status must be 'Initialized' for executing".

From debugging the problem, it appears that the child activity's ExecutionStatus is Closed and its ExecutionResult is Uninitialized.

But the MSDN doc for [ActivityExecutionContext.ExecuteActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.activityexecutioncontext.executeactivity.aspx) says that "If the status is Closed, the Activity is initialized and executed".

So why am I getting this exception and how can I avoid it?

Thanks,
Julien

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. The composite activity needs to create new ActivityExecutionContext for the child activity every time it wants to start the child activity.

**Executing the child activity in a new ActivityExecutionContext:**

```
ActivityExecutionContext context2 = executionContext.ExecutionContextManager.CreateExecutionContext(a);

// listen for the child's activity completion by implementing IActivityEventListener<ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs>
context2.Activity.RegisterForStatusChange(Activity.ClosedEvent, this);
context2.ExecuteActivity(context2.Activity);
```

**Cleaning up after the activity is Closed:**

```
// get the activity from the ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs, then...
activity.UnregisterForStatusChange(Activity.ClosedEvent, this);
ActivityExecutionContextManager executionContextManager = executionContext.ExecutionContextManager;

// close the child activity's execution context
executionContextManager.CompleteExecutionContext(executionContextManager.GetExecutionContext(activity));
```